# Regex for a combination of alphanumeric characters and range of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need a regex for PORT input, it must allow only inputs like this:

```
gei_1/8 or xgei-0/7/0/5
```

-It must allow underscore and hyphen only at the start: `gei_1` or `xgei-0`

-Then it must allow two digit numbers within a range of 0-48, separated by forward slash with no spaces between them. No more than three numbers: `/7/0/48`

-It cannot allow forward slash or anything at the end

Right now, I have the following Regex for the alphanumeric part: `/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/`

For the number part I have: `^(\d|1\d|2\d|3\d|4[0-8])\/(\d|1\d|2\d|3\d|4[0-8])\/(\d|1\d|2\d|3\d|4[0-8])$`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the forward slash 1 - 3 times you could use a range to match 0-48 and repeat that 1-3 times using a quantifier `{1,3}`

```
(?:\/(?:[0-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])){1,3}
```

The full pattern could look like

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[_-][A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\/(?:[0-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])){1,3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXQPkF/1)

Comment: Thank you very much!! @The fourth bird